# Converting Existing vue application into a vue CLI project

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I have an Existing Vue js app which was not built using Vue CLI, Now I want to convert this app to a Vue CLI project how can I achieve it and what changes I have to make to my existing app in order to make it successful